# SweetAlert 2 - Form Submission (Maximum call stack size exceeded)

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I have an issue with SweetAlert 2,  I am trying to submit a form when user click Okay.

Code is as follow (using jQuery)

```
$('#sa-params').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            buttonsStyling: false
          }).then(function () {
            swal(
              'Deleted!',
              'It has been deleted, FOREVER!',
              'success'
            )
            $('form#delete-form').submit();
          }, function (dismiss) {
            if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
              swal(
                'Cancelled',
                'Relax, nothing has been deleted :)',
                'error'
              )
            }
          })
          return false;
    });
```

Getting a following JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The main thing, that if i replace form submission with `console.log('success')` error is not showing.

According to bower.json:

jQuery version is: 2.2.4

SweetAlert2 version is: 5.3.8

Comment: nit: update your SweetAlert2 dependency to [^6.0.0](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v6.0.0), there's only one insignificant breaking change.

Answer (score 3):

`$('form#delete-form')[0].submit();`

Solves my problem, i dont know why I have not tried that...

Answer (score 0):

The solution 
in your file sweetalert.js

Comment out：

```
$targetElement.focus();
```

or in your file sweetalert.min.js

```
b.focus()
```

Probably in the 413 row.

source: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/104